# Categorical Clustering of Users Reading Habits

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have a data set with a set of users and a history of documents they have read, all the documents have metadata attributes (think topic, country, author) associated with them.

I want to cluster the users based on their reading history per one of the metadata attributes associated with the documents they have clicked on. This attribute has 7 possible categorical values and I want to prove a hypothesis that there is a pattern to the users' reading habits and they can be divided into seven clusters. In other words, that users will often read documents based on one of the 7 possible values in the particular metadata category.

Anyone have any advice on how to do this especially in R, like specific packages? I realize that the standard k-means algorithm won't work well in this case since the data is categorical and not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Cluster analysis **cannot be used to prove anything**.

The results are highly sensitive to normalization, feature selection, and choice of distance metric. So no result is trustworthy. Most results you get out are outright useless. So it's as reliable as a **proof by example**.

They should only be used for *explorative analysis*, i.e. to find patterns that you then **need to study with other methods**.